# How to reduce search result inaccuracies?

Tags: search, product, keyword

Context:

I am a Product Manager working on a database search product.

I used the search form and entered "Cov" in the disease search box. The autosuggest drop-down appeared, and I selected "Covid-19" from it. I clicked search, which led me to the results page. On this page, I chose Mayo Clinic from the "Companies" column, where I saw just 1 result under "Studies Column." However, the Mayo Clinic profile page actually contains 25 studies related to a specific term.

To find all 25 studies related to "Covid 19" at Mayo Clinic, I had to try various phrasings like Covid19, Covid 19, Covid -19, Covid - 19, Covid-19, Covid 19 Disease, Covid- 19 Infection, Covid 19 Vaccine, etc., in the disease search box.

Problem:

In this example, when I initially searched by selecting "Covid-19" from the drop-down, many relevant results were missing. I had to refine my search by trying various phrasings like Covid19, Covid 19, Covid -19, Covid - 19, Covid-19, Covid 19 Disease, Covid- 19 Infection, Covid 19 Vaccine, etc. This refined query returned the most accurate results.

The preferred search behavior should aim to provide as many relevant results as possible based on user-entered criteria and their search intent.

Users often face a challenge when trying to find specific information because there's a gap between the words they use to search (keywords) and the results they receive (information related to those keywords).

To address this challenge, users frequently need to experiment with different keyword variations because, although these phrases might be technically distinct in the database, they essentially mean the same thing to users.

Cause:

The database contains multiple variations of a specific term. While these phrases are technically distinct in the database, they essentially convey the same meaning to users.

From a user-centric perspective, the search results should ideally encompass all relevant variations to ensure a comprehensive and pertinent outcome.

Help Needed:

I'm grappling with how to communicate this issue effectively to my developers. They are suggesting that the envisioned implementation is challenging, but I believe it's a fundamental aspect of search functionality.